# PyAudio and Speech Recognition not working

Tags: python, download, pycharm, pyaudio

When I try to run speech_recognition, this happens:

```
C:\Users\CHERRY\WebOpener>python -m speech_recognition
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\CHERRY\WebOpener\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
        import pyaudio
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
        return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
      File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Users\CHERRY\WebOpener\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
        m = sr.Microphone()
      File "C:\Users\CHERRY\WebOpener\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
        self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
      File "C:\Users\CHERRY\WebOpener\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
        raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
    AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

But when I try to install PyAudio from the pipwin method

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

this happens:

```
C:\Users\CHERRY\WebOpener>pipwin install pyaudio
Package `pyaudio` found in cache
Downloading package . . .
https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/q4trcu4l/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CHERRY\WebOpener\venv\Scripts\pipwin-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pipwin==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'pipwin')())
  File "c:\users\cherry\webopener\venv\lib\site-packages\pipwin\command.py", line 103, in main
    cache.install(package)
  File "c:\users\cherry\webopener\venv\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 300, in install
    wheel_file = self.download(requirement)
  File "c:\users\cherry\webopener\venv\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 294, in download
    return self._download(requirement, dest)
  File "c:\users\cherry\webopener\venv\lib\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 290, in _download
    obj.start()
  File "c:\users\cherry\webopener\venv\lib\site-packages\pySmartDL\pySmartDL.py", line 267, in start
    urlObj = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=self.timeout, context=self.context)
  File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\CHERRY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I don't understand. PyAudio used to download from the pipwin method. But it is not downloading. Is there another method for downloading PyAudio?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I used

```
python -m pipwin install pyaudio
```